# Dirac delta in Dirichlet Distribution explanation

Tags: probability, dirac-delta

I am familiar with the following definition of the Dirac delta function:
$$ 
\delta = 
\begin{cases}
\infty, & \text{if } x=0 \\
0 & \text{if } x \neq 0
\end{cases}
$$

Now, I am reading this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0703715), and Appendix A defines Dirichlet probability density function as:

$$\text{Dir}(\{p_i\}) = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{\prod_{i=0}^{q-1} \Gamma(\alpha_i)} \delta\left( 1-\sum_{i=0}^{q-1} p_i \right) \prod_{i=0}^{a-1}p_i^{\alpha_i - 1}$$

Such that $p_i \in [0,1]$ and $\sum_{i=0}^{q-1} p_i = 1$. Hyperparameters $\{ \alpha_i\}$ are real and positive, and $\alpha = \sum_{i=0}^{q-1} \alpha_i \tag{1}$.

I am fairly certain I am misunderstanding the meaning of Dirac delta here. I know that it is used to normalize the pdf here. But from the definition of the Dirac delta I am familiar with, equation (1) tells me that the middle term should return infinity when $1-\sum_{i=0}^{q-1}p_i =0$, but we know that that is true. So, we will get infinity for whatever collection of $\{ p_i \}$ that sums to $1$? (clearly not).

Another conundrum for me is that for some reason you supply a collection of probabilities into Dirichlet pdf, instead of some $x$ for which you get a probability. Yeah.. I am a bit confused with this equation.

Answer (score 0):

$\{(p_0,\ldots,p_{q-1}):\sum p_i=1\}$ is not intended to be the domain where the Dirichlet probability density is defined. Instead, the density function is defined on the whole space $[0,1]^n$. Since the Dirac delta in the expression vanishes on $\{(p_0,\ldots,p_{q-1}):\sum p_i\ne1\}$, we have 
$$
\mathsf P\left(\sum_{i=0}^{q-1} p_i=1\right)=1
$$
which is the exact meaning of "the variates must satisfy... $\sum p_i=1$" in the paper.

For the latter question, $\{p_i\}$ is not a "*collection of probabilities*". It stands for values of the *random variables* in the distribution. This is indicated in the paper in the sentence before (A1): "the probability density function for $q$ **elements**". If you're feeling uncomfortable with this notation, you may just change $\{p_i\}$ to $\{x_i\}$.

Comment: where can I find an example of how to use this equation?

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal  Googling the name of the distribution gives two wiki pages and a lot of other references.

Comment: but I don't see dirac delta in there.. It is causing me some problems

Comment: it would only make sense if $\delta (1-\sum_{i=0}^{q-1} p_i) = 1 \text{ if } 1=\sum_{i=0}^{q-1} p_i$, instead of $\infty$

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal Not exactly. Let's consider a toy example. Think of a random variable $X$ with some distribution you like, say uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. Let $Y=X$. What's the probability density function of the joint distribution $(X,Y)$?

Comment: uniform on $[0,1]^2$? maybe not, because $Y=X$. It's a triangle. A triangle with equal probability of observing any element from that triangle

Comment: and probability of observing a random variable in any area of that triangle is proportional to the size of that area.

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal The distribution is supported on the diagonal, to be exact. You'll find the probability density function containing some $\delta$ function as is the case in OP.

Comment: correct, thanks. So what would the output of this function be if the sum of all elements $p_i$ is $1$? I need to understand how to calculate this quantity in practice.

Comment: it will be infinity when the sum of all elements is 1 (but as you said it is not intended to be defined on that domain). Thus, when it is not defined on the domain where the sum of all elements is 1, the output of the function is 0. Because dirac delta expression does not vanish but outputs 0? (clearly not, because you say that it vanishes)

Comment: on page 3 of that paper it actually says that $\sum_{s \in \mathcal{A}} p(s|s^k) =1$ for each $s^k$, which implies that it is intended domain?

Comment: Sorry for late response :-( It seems you are still confused, so I'll give another hint: Dirac delta has the key property $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x)dx$. This explains why the density can become infinity when the sum of all elements is $1$ and still make sense.

Comment: Hi, my friend just told me that that dirac in there is an abuse of notation and what is meant by that equation that the domain is in fact where all elements sum to 1. So it should behave like an indicator function